# Java JTable - sort

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

i have a problem with JTable and `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);` when I sort some column, the index table stays but order of row is different. 
How can i refresh my `AbstractTableModel` and keeping my sort.

Comment: beware: you are not supposed to do anything with your _model_! The very bone of Swing sorting mechanism is that there are two coordinate systems (one on your model, the other on your view). The table (more specifically: its RowSorter) keeps the mapping between both, then your application code uses the conversion methods to get hold of a particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not clear from your question, propably you have to set `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);`